# DEBUG = TRUE and you have "no urls configured." Yet, my URLs are configured and it displays standard DJANGO success page

Tags: python, django

SETTINGS.PY:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',

  'application.apps.ApplicationConfig', #already tried 'application',
[

ROOT_URLCONF = 'src.urls' #src is my 'mysite' or my djangoproject
```

URLs.py/src:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from application import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('', include('application.urls')),
  path('home/', views.signIn),
]
```

URLs.py/application:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.landing, name='landing'),
  path('create-account', views.createAccount, name='create-account'),
  path('forgot-password', views.forgotPassword, name='forgot-password'),
  path('home', views.signIn, name='home'),
]
```

DIRECTORY (HOW I FIRST HAD IT):

```
-env
-src
  -application
    -migrations
    -static
    -templates
    -__init__.py
    -urls.py
    -views.py
    -.....py
-src
  -__init__.py
  -settings.py
  -urls.py
  -.....py
manage.py
```

DIRECTORY (NOW):

```
-application
  -migrations
  -static
  -templates
  -__init__.py
  -urls.py
  -views.py
  -....py
-env
-src
  -src
    -__init__.py
    -settings.py
    -urls.py
    -....py
manage.py
```

I usually use the first directory, but I decided to not include my application in the src folder to see if that was the problem. However, they both display the same standard django successfully installed page.

Comment: What is the `ROOT_URLCONF` in your settings file? Which settings file is being used when you run `./manage.py runserver`?

Comment: What are `URLs.py/src` and `URLs.py/application`? If those are filenames, then you don't have a `urls.py`.

Comment: @Fractalism no those aren't the file names. the src is my django-admin startproject and the application is my django-admin startapp. I have them saved as urls.py as the name. One urls.py in my src folder, one in my application folder. My ROOT_URLCONF = 'src.urls'. I named it src instead of 'mysite' and I named the app 'application' instead of 'main' as they are listed in the documentation of django.

Comment: @Fractalism my ROOT_URLCONF is just the standard root when you render in your settings.py file. What should I change it to? Or should I just leave it be?

Comment: It might be helpful to share your directory structure

Comment: I edited my response and included the directories. I normally use the first directory, thinking it was the problem but I get the same problem with the second directory. I didn't feel like including all the .py files like models, apps, tests, asgi, or wsgi. So, I just put the dots. @Fractalism

Comment: Don't know if that's a good way to structure the project but... try adding an `__init__.py` in the outer `src` directory and change `ROOT_URLCONF` to `src.src.urls`.

Comment: what should I include in this __init__.py outside the src directory? Do I copy the code from the __init__.py inside of the src folder to the __init__.py outside of the folder? I just do not know what to put inside the file. @Fractalism

Comment: nvm I guess I put nothing because there's no code generated in either __init__.py file @Fractalism

Comment: That didn't work, so should I just use my first directory? I just tried out the second one to see if it would fix the problem.

Comment: If nothing else works, there's the option of modifying `sys.path` in `manage.py`.

Comment: wym modify? do you know the code to modify it because I got no clue what you goin on about with the sys.path?

Comment: I am looking at it, you talking about the main function at the end or the sys.argv argument?@Fractalism

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for using this directory structure? If not, then it's probably best to just stick with the defaults that django gives you when starting the project/app.